# Post Back variable value for captcha

Tags: php, javascript

i want the value of $code variable to get on my other page--- captcha.php.

```
captcha_image.php 


$captcha = new CaptchaCode();  //class defined in captcha_code.php
$code = str_encrypt($captcha->generateCode(6));  //function defined in captcha_code.php
$captcha1 = new CaptchaImages();
$captcha1-> GenerateImage($width,$height,str_decrypt($code));


captcha.php

<img style="cursor: pointer;width: 50px;height: 50px;" src="refresh.png" onclick="refresh_captcha();"/>
<input type="hidden" name="security_check" value="<?php echo $code; ?>">  // want value of $code here

<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh_captcha()
{
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
    img.src = 'captcha_images.php';
    jQuery("#captcha_img").attr("src",img.src);
}
</script>
```

I cant include captcha_images.php file in my code and even dont want it to be done using sessions, tried that way.If anyone has a solution for this, please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is save code into SESSION.

For example:

captcha_image.php:

```php
session_start();
$captcha = new CaptchaCode();
$code = $captcha->generateCode(6);
$captcha1 = new CaptchaImages();
$captcha1-> GenerateImage($width,$height,$code);
$_SESSION["captchacode"] = $code;
```

And check correctness after submit of the form:

```php
session_start();
...
if($_SESSION["captchacode"]!=$_POST["security_check"]){
    echo "Wrong captcha!";
}else{
    // captcha is correct, process the form
}
```

Comment: I need the solution without using sessions, sorry forgot to tell that before.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use cookies and session, you cannot get information from captcha_image.php which returns only image. You must generate information in else request, for example:

```
<img id="captcha_img" src="captcha_images.php?encoded_code=<?php echo $code ?>" onclick="refresh_captcha();"/>
<input type="hidden" id="captcha_hidden" name="security_check" value="<?php echo $code ?>">
<script type="text/javascript">
function refresh_captcha()
{
    // generate_captcha.php returns only encoded captcha
    $.get('generate_captcha.php', function(encoded_code) {
        $('#captcha_hidden').val(encoded_code);
        $('#captcha_img').attr("src","captcha_images.php?encoded_code="+encoded_code);
    });
}
</script>
```

Here `generate_captcha.php` returns encoded captcha, `captcha_images.php` doesnt generate code, only decode code from hims parameter `encoded_code` and this code is also inserted into hidden.